# dropdown in google sheet give me "not a valid cell" error

Tags: google-sheets, formula

Im trying to get the names from "Imput user list" (coming from "raw users list) selecting the dropdown in tab "input".
But it only works for AT
if i select the others i get this error
Error
Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is 'CA'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.

here is the doc
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zlGZvRrj-r7RoZbQ241LkNuXKqdngjZG7VJ421b9F6E/edit#gid=770062287
any idea?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your named ranges are all broken. fixed it for `IE` and added new one for `CA`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it works, but not if i select USA

Comment: you have to **`update/add`** the named range for USA just like how its done for AT, IE or CA

Comment: i did it, both in the dropdown and in the input user list

Comment: goto `Data > Named Ranges` and you will see the list of custom named ranges added ( as in the screenshot I added above). You'll find most of them broken with `#REF` error.  the working named ranges are of `AT, IE, CA` in that list. create one for USA as well similar to the working ranges.

Comment: thanks a lot! working now! :D